# Using Facebook App to obtain contacts and profile details for user on my website, it works for some users and not for other

Tags: facebook, cakephp-2.0

I integrated Facebook API for importing Facebook contacts as well as profile details. It was working well before. Now it allows syncing for few users and some users are unable to acquire any Facebook details. I am using CakePHP for development and the code was working before. Now for few users the following error is obtained

An error occurred. Please try again later.

For some users I am getting the following error

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a sub-domain of one of the App's domains.

For some users there is no error message but the account details are not obtained while some are successfully able to sync their accounts and obtain the details.

Kindly help me fix the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your errors are pointing that your app settings might not be correct. Please check them

Answer (score 0):

FB has updated privacy policy recently, may be that causes error. If someone has private profile, FB may not be allowing it. Check their profile status (Is it private?). Google search, **One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL** you will get many results. It may help you.